# Automatically prepend executable Perl scripts using .htaccess (like php_value auto_prepend_file)?

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess, perl, executable, server-side-includes

I have previously built sites using PHP, where I **automatically included header and footer html** using the following lines in **.htaccess** on an **Apache** host:

```
php_value auto_prepend_file "/var/www/html/parts/header.htm"
php_value auto_append_file  "/var/www/html/parts/footer.htm"
```

In these files I could put executable PHP code.

My current project is **written in Perl, not in PHP**.

**Is there any way to automatically prepend and append executable Perl files using .htaccess?**

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how exactly you're using perl. There are several different frameworks that would do what you want - e.g. HTML::Mason has the autohandler that will load stuff for you. There's also a perl module called [Apache Sandwich](http://snowhare.com/utilities/perldoc2tree/example/Apache/Sandwich.html) that might be what you're looking for.